# How do you put each line of a file into a list all the while wrapping the resulting lists into a list?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    results = []
    while True:
        try:
            fileName = input("Enter the name of the data file: ")
            with open(fileName) as inputfile:
                for line in inputfile:
                    results.append(line.strip().split(','))
            break
        except:
            print ("No such file!\n")
    printGrid(results)

def printGrid(results):
    for i in range(len(results)):
        for j in range(len(results[i])):
            for x in range(len(results[i][j])):
                results[i][j][x].split(' ')
            print(results[i][j])
```

I have a file that looks like this:

```
II--------
I--II------ 
I----IIII-- 
I--------III
I------------
I--------II-
I--III---II 
I--II-I
IIIII
```

I want to be able to read this file and put the entire file in a list, and then each line in a list in the original list. I also want to print out the "grid' with a space between each character.
However, it seems like I'm missing something obvious. I just can't get it to work. I have been able to get the file in a list, but I can't get each line into a list, and I'm also unable to put a space in between each character.

As must be obvious, I'm a complete beginner to Python. I would greatly appreciate any help. I have tried the split(), but it doesn't work like I want it to.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `try/except` section in your `main` function with:

```
try:
    fileName = input("Enter the name of the data file: ")
    with open(filename) as inputfile:
       result = [ [c for c in line] for line in inputfile.readlines() ]
    break
except IOError:
    print ("No such file!\n")
```

(Note that this explicitly catches `IOError`. It's bad practice to have a "bare" `except` clause, as it would catch and misreport any other error that occured.)

This uses a nested list comprehension to produce a list of lists. List comprehensions are a shorthand for creating a list and appending values to it. It's equivalent to:

```
result = []
for line in inputfile.readlines():
    row = []
    for char in line:
        row.append(char)
    result.append(row)
```

`printGrid` can be replaced with:

```
def printGrid(results):
    for row in results:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, is there a way to not have spaces between each row when printing?

Comment: Yes, use an empty string instead of a space: `print(''.join(row))`

Comment: But does that not remove the space between each character in a line? I'm referring to referring to removing the space after each line when it prints.

Comment: Okay, nvm, I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help though!